# Dynamically Specify Images to Appear in a Repeater & DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a Group table and an Images table in an SQL Server Database:

Group table: (Group_Id is connected to groupNo, below)

[image: sql1]

Images table:

[image: sql 2]

This code below displays a DataList for each row in the Groups table, but does not seperate the images into their relevant groups. Instead, it displays all the images in each row:

```
 <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptGroupGallery" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 10px">
                                                            <a id="imageLink" href="~/SlideImages/<%# Eval("filename") %>" title="<%#Eval("imageDesc") %>" rel="lightbox[Brussels]">
                                                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "~/SlideImages/" + Eval("filename") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:DataList>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

And here is my C#:

```
 static String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //find the nested datalist and cast it as one
    DataList datalist = e.Item.FindControl("dlImages") as DataList;

    //find the correct group id of the item
    string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Group_Id").ToString();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE (Group_Id = '" + Group_Id +  "')", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    //bind data to the nested datalist with the Group_Id in the where clause of the query
    datalist.DataSource = dt;
    datalist.DataBind();
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Trying to display events using repeater
    SqlConnection connR;
    string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    connR = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Groups", connR);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    //rptGroupGallery.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    //rptGroupGallery.DataBind();
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

I would like to display a DataList for each row in the Groups table. This DataList will display images from the Images table where the groupNo = Group_Id.

I've tried surrounding my code with a Repeater, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post what you tried, maybe you just missed something ? Nested repeaters/datalists _should_ work, it can get messy but I've done it a number of times.

Comment: @sh1rts Hi, I've posted my Repeater above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sh1rts already mentioned, you can use something like a Repeater and nest the DataList. You then need to add a `OnItemDataBound` event to the Repeater to fill the DataList in each item with the correct data.

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Title") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" RepeatDirecton="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a id="imageLink" href="~/SlideImages/<%# Eval("filename") %>" title="<%# Eval("imageDesc") %>" rel="lightbox[Brussels]">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "~/SlideImages/" + Eval("filename") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //find the nested datalist and cast it as one
    DataList datalist = e.Item.FindControl("dlImages") as DataList;

    //find the correct group id of the item
    string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Group_Id").ToString();

    //bind data to the nested datalist with the Group_Id in the where clause of the query
    datalist.DataSource = dt;
    datalist.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've pasted in your solution, but where else do I reference 'dt' in the Code behind?

Comment: `dt` is your DataTable you fill with `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SlideShowTable", con);` in your snippet.

Comment: I've updated my code above with everything that I currently, have

Comment: Hi, I've tried to adapt your solution, and have posted all my code ATM above. But it is displaying no images at the moment

Comment: You have to use `Group_Id` in the query to begin with: `SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE (Group_Id = '" + Group_Id + "')`, otherwise you'll get all the data.

Comment: And `not displaying images` is not the result of my example. You need to adapt it to make sure it corresponds with your correct database table, columns and file system. Check the generated HTML and see if the path of the images is correct.

Comment: Is there a need to have anything in Page_Load? Or should Repeater1_ItemDataBound take care of displaying the images?

Comment: Yes, and you have to bind data to the Repeater itself. Probably with the query `SELECT * FROM Groups`?

Comment: I've posted all my C# above, including the WHERE (Group_Id) clause. Could you point out where in my C# I am going wrong please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132492/discussion-between-sweg-and-vdwwd).