# Retrieving SQL Server Table ID & Generating DataLists Based on that ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a Group table and an Images table in an SQL Server database. Each image is linked to a different Group when they are inserted into the table.

I am trying to display a separate photo gallery for each row in the Group table.

The below Repeater creates a DataList based on the number of rows in the Groups table. However, it displays all images rather than those which are linked to that specific group.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptGroupGallery" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:DataList DataKeyField="ID" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" CellPadding="5" runat="server" DataSourceID="dataSource">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                                            <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("filename","~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' title='<%#Eval("imageDesc") %>' rel="lightbox[Brussels]" runat="server">
                                                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("filename", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" Width="112" Height="84" />
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:DataList>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BallinoraDBConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SlideShowTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code below:

```
 SqlConnection connR;
    string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    connR = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Groups", connR);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    rptGroupGallery.DataSource = dt;
    rptGroupGallery.DataBind();
```

Below is a sketch of what I would like:
[image: sketch]

Group SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups] (
[Group_Id]   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Group_Name] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
[Group_Desc] NVARCHAR (1000) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Group_Id] ASC)
```

);

Slideshow SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlideShowTable] (
[ID]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[filename]  VARCHAR (250) NULL,
[imageDesc] VARCHAR (250) NULL,
[groupNo]   INT           NULL);
```

Also, sample data:
[image: smpleData]

[image: smpleData]

Here are the table structures I am working with:

[image: sql1]

[image: sql2]

Below is the output when I have 5 rows in the Group table, and 3 images in the Images table, all with different Group_ID's.

[image: screenShot]
I understand the SqlDataSource's Select Command is "SELECT * FROM tableName".

To seperate the groups, I know that I will need to add a parameter to this command (to pass the various ID's from the Group table).

But I'm not sure how to add that within the repeater so that it counts the number of rows.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this?

Comment: This looks shockingly similar to your previous post on this exact topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494215/dynamically-specify-images-to-appear-in-a-repeater-datalist Sadly both of your posts are lacking any real details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide the code behind you have used in order to get better understanding.

Comment: @SeanLange In the screenshot above - there are 5 data-lists, because there are 5 rows in my Groups table. Each image has a Group_ID attached. Rather than all images be displayed for each row, I want to display images in their relevant data-list.

Comment: @SeanLange In other words, I only want images with Group_ID = 1 to be displayed in the first data-list, images with Group_ID = 2 displayed in the second data-list, etc.

Comment: Well that doesn't clear anything up. Remember we can't see your screen, we have no knowledge of your data or your project. We have no idea what your data is like or what this picture is supposed to be showing us. In short, you have put a lot of time into a pretty picture but you forgot the important part....explaining clearly what you want. I see 15 pictures above. What is Group_ID 1? I am pretty sure the solution is simple, but without a defined problem there is nothing anybody can do.

Comment: @SeanLange I have added the C# code above, and my tables. Group_ID (PK) is a foreign key in the second table (groupNo)

Comment: So, the expected result should be one photo of each type >?

Comment: Can you post actual ddl instead of a picture of what your table looks like? Also a few rows of sample data would help a LOT.

Comment: I have a feeling that we can do this a completely different way but it is not really clear what you want as output. do you want however many rows all with the same pictures? Or do the pictures vary for each group? Are you always going to have 3 images as a maximum?

Comment: @Null I have posted a sketch of the expected result above

Comment: @SeanLange When you upload an image, you specify which group it is associated with. Then all images are to be displayed, separated into their relevant groups

Comment: OK. So is there a maximum of 3 images per group? Once you post the ddl for the tables I can help you with the sql. This looks like a typical crosstab or conditional aggregation. What is increasingly confusing is you talk about an images table but your code has a table named slideshow. >.<

Comment: @SeanLange I have uploaded the code above. There is no limit to the number of images per group. I have only uploaded 3 so far.